# Kendo Grid - How to Arrow Keys to navigate over the rows?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I would like to use UP and DOWN Arrow Keys to navigate over the rows in Kendo Grid. 
LEFT and RIGHT Arrow Keys to navigate over the the cells in Kendo Grid.

I tried to find something in official documentation, but without luck:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/keyboard-navigation

How can i do it i Kendo Grid please?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using keydown event on grid:

```
var data = $("#grid").data('kendoGrid');
var arrows = [37, 38, 39, 40];
data.table.on("keydown", function (e) {
console.log(e.keyCode);
  if (arrows.indexOf(e.keyCode) >= 0) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      data.select($("#grid_active_cell"));
    },1);
  }
});
```